# Async function returns [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to return an async function but I either get `promise: < { PENDING } >` or `[object Promise]` instead of `[object Object]`

I've tried returning the value using `Promise.resolve(value)`, `Promise.resolve().then(return value)`, `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve(value)}`

from top-level to bottom my code looks like:

```
//Top-Level
const getNext = require('getNext');
const next = getNext({
  page,
  value,
  name,
  id,
});


//getNext
const controllerMap = {
  intro: introController
};
async function getNext({ page, value, name, id}) {
  const controller = controllerMap[name];
  return await controller({
    page,
    value,
    name,
    id
  });
}

// Controller
async function introController({ page, value, id }) {
  switch(page)
    case 10:
      // Do something async ie:
      await db.query
    default: return intro[page]
};
```

If I take off `async` and `await` from the functions and extract my low-level `db.query` from the `controller` case into it's own `async function` I just get `promise: < { PENDING } >` so I'm thinking it's because the top level functions aren't waiting for it to resolve. However, when I make those functions async they return promises for my static data. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around these nested promises/async functions.

Comment: you have to `await` the call to `getNext`

Comment: The goal of async/await is to minimize how many times you actually have to explicitly create and `.then()` Promises.  You need to use `await` alongside the `async` or use `.then()`.

Comment: @DanielA.White — They can't. You can only `await` inside an `async` function, and the call to `getNext` is not inside a function.

Comment: then make it one.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot make asynchronous code synchronous.

The `await` keyword lets you write code that *looks* synchronous, but is really asynchronous.

You can only use `await` inside a function which is `async`.

To make `await` work, **all** `async` functions return promises. Those promises resolve to be the return value of the function.

In short: You have the normal and expected behaviour, and you can't prevent an `async` function from returning a promise.

Comment: So how can I achieve the desired implementation? I need to make the db call inside that specific case and then perform logic on the results.

Comment: @Nathan you have to do the work in a `.then()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding an await to the top level `getNext()` aka

```
const next = await getNext({
  page,
  value,
  name,
  id,
});
```

which is inside an async `router.post` call. So the answer is: make sure all functions are async all the way to the top so that they wait for eachother.